# WinJS binding to nested control

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am trying to implement semantic zoom control in my application. Here is a fragment of one of my pages:

```
<div id="semanticZoomDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom">

            <div id="zoomedInListView"
                class="win-selectionstylefilled"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: groupedList.dataSource; winControl.groupDataSource: groupedList.groups.dataSource;"
                data-win-options="{ 
                itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'), 
                groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerTemplate'), 
                selectionMode: 'none', 
                tapBehavior: 'none', 
                swipeBehavior: 'none' 
            }">
            </div>

            <div id="zoomedOutListView"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: groupedList.groups.dataSource;"
                data-win-options="{  
                itemTemplate: select('#semanticZoomTemplate'), 
                selectionMode: 'none', 
                tapBehavior: 'invoke', 
                swipeBehavior: 'none' 
            }">
            </div>

        </div>
```

The problem is, that semanticZoomDiv is empty.

However, if I remove attribute

```
data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom"
```

from semanticZoomDiv two ListViews render and are correctly filled with data. It seems like WinJS has problems with binding data to nested controls? (ListView controls are inside SemanticZoom control - after removal of outer SemanticZoom control data binds correctly).

I managed to make semantic zoom work using binding to global namespace via data-win-options, but I want to provide data for my page through view model, hence my trials to use data-win-bind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an object scoping issue, but am not on Win8 at the moment to verify.  If I'm right, you can expose `groupedList` from your JavaScript code similarly to this.

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("YourApp", {
    groupedList: groupedList,
});
```

and then change your declarative binding to include the `YourApp` namespace.  That way your data is not in the global namespace.

Alternatively, you can do the data binding in the .js file

```
zoomedInListView.winControl.itemDataSource = groupedList.dataSource;
zoomedInListView.winControl.groupDataSource = groupedList.groups.dataSource;
zoomedOutListView.winControl.itemDataSource = groupedList.groups.dataSource;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I mentioned in my question that I managed to make it work using global namespace (like you pointed out), but I am using view model. After some research I found out that function processAll doesn't support nested controls (e. g. ListView inside Semantic Zoom) - binding wasn't initialized for nested ListViews. Solution is to execute processAll for all nested controls' containers.